# Are JavaScript classes acceptable Node modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Bear with me as I lead you through the process that elicited my question.

I'm working on a CLI app in node and I'm using objects to encapsulate my business logic using this pattern:

```
// my-project/lib/widget/myobject.js

var MyObject = function(x) {
  this.x = x;
};

MyObject.prototype.getX = function() {
  return this.x;
};

module.exports = MyObject;
```

I'm also testing these objects:

```
// my-project/test/lib/widget/myobject.spec.js

var MyObject = require('../../../lib/widget/myobject.js');

describe('MyObject', function() {
  ...
});
```

At one point I was unhappy with the naming and directory structure I had chosen. I found myself tediously counting those parent directory references (`..`) in several spec files when rewriting the relative paths. I figured there must be an easier way to reference a root directory containing these object definitions.

One of the recommendations I found [here](https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#avoiding-) suggested "putting application-specific modules into node_modules".

Now, as I understand modules, they are the packages I download from npm and use in my project. They contain libraries of useful things with a single API exported to me when I call `require`. This is not how I view the simple single-purpose classes built specifically for the internal use of my application.

If you've stuck with me this far, thank you! Here is my question:

How do I make the internals of my application more "modular" so it properly follows the intent of the Node module system while remaining object oriented?

Comment: In node when working with objects I'll normally just store and import them from an asset folder. A lot of this depends on preference, build tools, and deployment which is out the scope of my expertise. The node_modules method or more or less just an asset folder where you're able to import static assets, and would work fine (but I wouldn't recommend mixing npm assets with your own personally built ones).

Comment: You're right, it's like a static asset folder, but it has the added benefit of being a default place where Node looks for modules. That's the draw for me. I'd be using require('myobject') instead of require('../../../lib/widget/myobject.js'). My apprehension is in exactly what you mentioned next: mixing public modules with private ones. That's what prompted my question. I'm basically asking "Am I doing this right? Or is there some other convention that makes more sense with these objects?" Mixing feels really kludgy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how suitable this is for production or for modules you plan on distributing but in your main file you could add this:

```
process.env.NODE_PATH = __dirname;
require('module').Module._initPaths();
```

which would let you always require modules relative to the folder containing your main file. I.e. if you had a file in:

```
library/some_file.js
```

then in `tests/some_other_file.js` you could just do:

```
require('library/some_file');
```

Or as an alternative you could add this in your main file:

```
global.__base = __dirname + '/';
```

and then in your other modules require using:

```
var MyObject = require(__base + 'my-project/lib/widget/myobject');
```

Comment: Yes! I found these solutions as well. I immediately discounted the NODE_PATH solution because of a statement in the link I provided: "node and browserify both support but discourage the use of $NODE_PATH."

Comment: (Correct me if I'm wrong.) I also don't think this solution works with my test runner. Since the spec file only requires the js file with the class definition, I won't get the path finagling from main.js.